# Rpart Improvement Score with Information Gain

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

I've been recently working with RPART and ran into a calculation I don't understand.

When working with information gain, how is "improve" or variable importance calculated (they seem to be the same from my tests).

As a dummy example, I tried learning the following table:

```
   happy,class
   yes,p
   no,n
```

with the command:

`fit <-rpart(class ~ happy,data=train,parms = list(split="information"),minsplit=0)`

It's simple, and returns the expected tree  with the root and then each leaf containing one element.

Where this gets confusing, is that the improvement given for the split is 1.386294.

I would expect the improvement here to be 1 (going from entropy 1 to entropy 0 in the children), what am I missing?

Comment: Hi Greg, welcome to stackoverflow! Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that people can help you

Comment: Hi Julian, I cleaned up the original post - general insight into how the statistic is calculated is also welcome!

Comment: rpart is an implementation of CART.  It uses GINI to decide node splits,   not entropy.

Comment: Hi @G5W, while this is true by default, when split="information" is specified, it should use entropy. Source: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart/vignettes/longintro.pdf page 23.

Comment: I see that you used that. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to answer this one, it's because RPART is using the natural log.

Thus, it seems that the improve score is the improvement in the entropy scaled by the number of elements in the node.

The entropy in the root node is : -ln(1/2)*1/2*2 + -ln(1/2)*1/2*2 = -ln(1/2)*2 1.38. The entropy in the leaf nodes is both 0.

Why they use natural log, I have no idea.